# How to obtain thumbnail path from image path in android?

Tags: java, android

Basically i have image path that looks like this: /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/image.jpg
And i need to get a path to thumbnail from it, in a fastest possible way.

I am trying to use MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail, but no matter what i pass i get null cursor.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
This is the function that brings ALL of the image paths and thumbnail paths and stores them in a String. What I need is a function that returns thumbnail path for a specific image path (/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/image.jpg). Thanks

```
public String getThumbPaths(ThumbContext ctx) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external");

    Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails(ctx
            .getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);

    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String id = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    String orientation="1";

    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String imageId = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        Cursor images = ctx.getActivity().managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                filePathColumn, id,
                new String[] { imageId }, null);

        String filePath = "";
        if (images != null && images.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = images.getString(images
                    .getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]));
        }

        ExifInterface exifReader;
        try {
            exifReader = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            orientation=exifReader.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }


        stringBuilder.append(cursor.getString(1) + ";");
        stringBuilder.append(filePath + ";");
        stringBuilder.append(orientation + ";");
        orientation="1";

    }
    //cursor.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: queryMiniThumbnail is to be used on an already inserted image

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it right, your image is not in the Media database. You can use

```
ThumbnailUtils.extractTumbnail()
```

which requires only a Bitmap.

Comment: I need path not the image, image is there and thumbnail also.
`Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(ctx
    .getActivity().getContentResolver(), ContentUris.parseId(Uri.parse("file://" + "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/image.jpg")),
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);`

Comment: the expected uri is the one from the media content provider. Chances are your image is not in the media content provider. If it is, you need to find its id.

Comment: Thanks. Can you drop a hint on how do i find id from given image path?

Answer (score -1):

Try it out. it will help you to set the Thumbnail of image set to ImageView.

```
 im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    byte[] imageData = null;

    try 
    {

    final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;
    //InputStream is=getAssets().open("apple-android-battle.jpg");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/apple.jpg");
    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

    Float width = new Float(imageBitmap.getWidth());
    Float height = new Float(imageBitmap.getHeight());
    Float ratio = width/height;
    imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, (int)(THUMBNAIL_SIZE * ratio), THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    imageData = baos.toByteArray();
    im.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: what's with reinventing the wheel ? ThumbnailsUtils does that for you.